# Passing string array's through methods in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, authentication, methods

I'm very new to C#

I'm trying to create code that takes input from a user and saves it in an array in the SignUp() method and then if I call the Profile() method it displays the personal information

The error that occurs is when I try and call the Profile() method in the main line it says "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'privinfo' of Profile(string[])' "

```
using System;

namespace SDD_Assessment_2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //SignUp();
            var privInfo = SignUp();
            Profile(privInfo);         
        }

        static string[] SignUp()
        {
            string[] privinfo = new string[4];
            Console.Write("First Name: ");
            privinfo[0] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Last Name: ");
            privinfo[1] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Email: ");
            privinfo[2] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Password: ");
            privinfo[3] = Console.ReadLine();
            return privinfo;
        }
        static void Profile(string[] privinfo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + privinfo[0] + " " + privinfo[1]);
            Console.WriteLine("Email: " + privinfo[2]);
            Console.WriteLine("Password: " + privinfo[3]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to **provide** the array **returned by** `Signup` **to** `Profile`.

Comment: How do I provide the array? does putting it inside the profile() method parameters not achieve that? @HimBromBeere

Comment: Only because you have to methods that have a variable with the same name doesn´t mean those variables are the same. In fact those have absoluetely nothing to di with one another, that´s what scopes are about. Both variables only exist in the method where they are declared.

Comment: You have to provide the array as proposed by sagi.

Comment: How do I provide the array? I thought I was already proposing the array when I put the array name inside the parameters... P.S I updated the code I have ^

Comment: @HimBromBeere ^

Comment: and what doesn´t work within your updated code? From my perspective that should do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not saving the value returned from `SignUp()`, so when the method ends, the **local** data is deleted. You need to catch the value, and pass it to `Profile` method, which expects an array of strings as an input.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var privInfo = SignUp();
    Profile(privInfo);
    ...
}
```

Comment: This fixed the original problem and there is no more errors, however when I call the Profile() method it runs the SignUp() method code, but I want it so it is an option to display what they input.

Comment: @Tris From the code in your question `Profile` does not run `SignUp`, so I assume that´s not your **actual** code.

Comment: Does this - "var privInfo = SignUp();" call the SignUp() function? Because if so, that is why, although I just thought it savedthe value returned from SignUp() @HimBromBeere

Comment: "I just thought it saved the value from signUp()" ... signUp is a method, so to save the value from it, of course you need to run it.. Also, every method followed by () is calling the method.

Comment: see my comment to your question. Of course `SignUp` is run, however you have to **use the value returned from it**.

Comment: @HimBromBeere sorry for the @, but do have any posts or sites that explain in detail return value rules?